# How to use sqlmap to scan entire app (full site scan)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, penetration-testing, sqlmap

Suppose I have a rails app running on http://localhost:3000/, how can I make sqlmap crawl an entire app and attempt injection on every single form it finds?

Note: my app is about 20 pages, so it shouldn't be a monumental task, I just hope to find a general solution rather than coding up specific instructions for each page/app I wish to test

I know I can scan one endpoint (in this case `characters/1`) with:

```
sqlmap --dbms SQLite -u http://localhost:3000/ characters/1 --tables
```

But I wonder if there's a 'comprehensive' way to have sqlmap crawl the site testing everything it can think of?

Reference: Example from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-Dnys7_ESE&t=43m02s)

Comment: How about calling sqlmap explicitly in your test suite? While I can think of things like using `rails routes` or creating a rake task that uses the routes collection it seems like it would be pretty brittle and more work then its worth-